# How to filter posts of a paticular label in blogger?

Tags: filter, label, blogger, posts, blogspot

I want to show posts of only one label in the blog posts section in homepage. But posts of that label shouldn't be filtered only from the homepage. I meant, if I choose to show 7 posts in homepage, there must be 7 posts in home page and they all should be of that chosen label.

I replaced,

```
<b:include data='post' name='post'/>
```

with below code,

```
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
            <b:if cond='data:label.name == &quot;MY LABEL&quot;'>
          <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
  </b:if>
        </b:loop>
```

It filters posts of MY LABEL, but it filters posts from only first 7 posts. So there are always less than 7 posts in posts section in home page. How can I fix this to show first 7 posts of MY LABEL in posts section?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
    <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
        <b:if cond='data:label.name == &quot;YOUR LABEL&quot;'>
            <b:include data='post' name='post' />
        </b:if>
    </b:loop>
    <b:else />
    <b:include data='post' name='post' />
</b:if>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.